# Openstack ( using libvirt image type as LVM )- Very low IOPS

Tags: kvm-virtualization, openstack, libvirt, linux-kernel, openstack-nova

As part of the base line testing, able to see qcow is providing much higher iops compare to the LVM.

Ideally it should be the reverse ( as per my knowledge gathering ) Kindly please advise me on how can i get the better iops while using LVM

Usage:

Will create one VG before, feed the data to openstack nova.conf under libvirt

Basically all vm boot & ephemeral disk will created as logical volume under the specified VG.

Below is my disk libvirt configuration

Can you please suggest ?

Comment: I saw similar thread  https://serverfault.com/questions/606080/linux-kvm-very-slow-disk-io/1082844#1082844 ( i couldn't find the solution )

Comment: Using cinder with LVM backend is not considered as production ready. This was stated in the openstack-discuss mailing list a while back, I can't find the link at the moment. It's fine to learn how openstack works or for testing purposes, of course. But reconsider before using that in production.
As for the performance issue, you don't show any benchmark results and how you tested it. Can you share more details what exactly you're trying and what the results are? And also more details about your environment could be helpful.